# Scala: Using Trait + Companion object to enumerate implementations

Tags: scala

My question is: is this an antipattern:

I have a sealed scala trait with a dozen or two implementations - say something like this:

```scala
package com.erik.logic

sealed trait FailureReason {
  def why: String
}

case object A extends FailureReason {
  val why = "just because"
}
case class B(why: String) extends FailureReason
// ...
case object Z extends FailureReason {
  val why = "idk"
}
```

Imports can get ugly (or above 6, start using the `._` style according to most styleguides I've read).

*One option is to put them all inside a companion object to the trait, which I can then import and refer to in a manner similar to an Enum.* **Is this an antipattern?**

```scala
package com.erik.logic

trait FailureReason {
  def why: String
}

object FailureReason
  case object A extends FailureReason { ... }
  case class B(why: String) extends FailureReason
  // ...
}

// otherFile.scala
import com.erik.logic.FailureReason

... reason match {
  case FailureReason.A => something
  case FailureReason.B(y) => other(y)
  case FailureReason.C => etc
}


// yetAnotherFile.scala
import com.erik.logic.FailureReason.{A, B, J, Q}

// ... badThing match {
  case SomethingBad => ReasonWrapper(A)
  case SomethingTerrible => ReasonWrapper(B("terrible"))
  case SomethingMeh => ReasonWrapper(Q)
}
```

Comment: I do not think it is an anti-pattern, I had used it a couple of times. I had also see it used in other projects like in [**Scapegoat**](https://github.com/sksamuel/scapegoat/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/sksamuel/scapegoat/Level.scala). However, there is [one point against it](https://github.com/alexandru/scala-best-practices/blob/master/sections/2-language-rules.md#217-should-not-define-case-classes-nested-in-other-classes), but it is related to java serialization, if you do not need that, it should not be a problem. - Anyways, this probably will end being opinion based.

Comment: That point about serialization isn't quite correct. It says "do not declare case classes inside another class/object", but that explain how you should not be declaring cases classes inside an object _that contains a lot of other data_, which is not the same thing.

Comment: @Dima just for curiosity, the problem is still the same, right? If you define case classes inside an object, then if you need to serialize such case class, it has to serialize the object _(and thus, the definition of all the case classes)_ too, or not? - I am some what interested because a college told me that during a review a few days ago, where I defined a couple of case classes inside an object inside another object just to avoid creating a couple of folder, so I would like to know if that is really a problem _(however, we do not really care about java serialization anyways)_.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez serialization does not serialize definitions. Only data.

Comment: @Dima OK, thus it only had tod serialize the reference to the parent objects, which is not so bad. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

It's not an "anti-pattern", it's fine. You *can* BTW, import the same way at the package level: `import com.erik.logic.{A, B, J, Q}`, so no need to put them inside the object *for that reason* (but there is nothing wrong with it either, if you want to do it anyway).

One note, you should probably make your trait `sealed`. That way you can take advantage of the compiler warning you if you forgot some `case` clause, and your `match` isn't exhaustive.

Comment: Hi, just curious, is it really necessary to `extends` the `trait`? In another word, what's the benefit if it does not `extends` the `trait` like [this example](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/master/MasterMessages.scala) in Spark source code? Thanks.

Comment: @jack the reason to extend the trait is so you can reference it elsewhere. If you have a `sealed trait Foo`, and a bunch of implementations extending it, and then you create a function like `def foo(bar: Foo)` you can be sure that the `bar` that can be passed in is always one of those types.

Comment: Thanks. Just want to understand, in this [example](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/master/MasterMessages.scala), all the `case object`s are not `extend`ing `MasterMessages `, what's the point of having the `sealed trait MasterMessages` then?

Comment: Yeah, I don't know. I don't think there's any point in having it.